# Export Google Calendar App Data

Tags: calendar, backup

Is there a way to export all the data from the google calender app? For whatever reason, my google account has been suspended, and while I desperately try and sort this out I'm seeing what my phone can do for me. Because of this, I'm unable to to access the calendar online, but the apps cache still has quite a lot of events and data - if I could back this up some how that would be awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [iCal Import/Export](https://market.android.com/details?id=at.aichbauer.ical&feature=search_result). It looks like it should be able to export your calendar data. It will allow you to export your calendar(s) to iCal files. I haven't actually tried the application, so I am not sure if it uses the local calendar database on the device, or it it attempts to connect directly to google calendar.

Comment: It didn't occur to me, but my suspended google account means no access to the market. Gutted. +1 though, it looks like a perfect app to do backups in the future.